# Inconsistent accessibility: base class is less accessible than child class

Tags: c#, inheritance, base-class

I am reading book "C# 4.0 in a nutshell" by Joseph Albabari and Ben Albabari. From there I find a topic restrictions on access modifiers. Page 91, Topic "Restrictions on Access Modifiers".

Quoting from the book.

> The compiler prevents any inconsistent use of access modifiers. For
>   example, a sub- class itself can be less accessible than a base class,
>   but not more

So this says that base class should be equally or more accessible than subclass. So if base class is internal then subclass should be either private or internal. If base class is private and sub class is public then compile time error will be generated. While trying this in Visual Studio I found some strange behavior.

Try 1: Base is private and sub class is private (Works, right behavior) This also works if both are internal, public.

```
private class A { }
private class B : A { }         // Works
```

Try 2: Base is private and sub class is public or internal (This fails, right behavior)

```
private class A { }
public class B : A { }          // Error
```

Try 3 : Base is internal and sub is public (This works, but it should fail. As Base is less accessible than sub class

```
internal class A { }
public class B : A { }          // Works, but why
```

Now my question is why Try 3 didn't failed? Sub class is public and is more accessible than base class which is internal. Even the book says this should fail. But Visual Studio compiled this successfully. This should work or not?

**Edit:**

I created a new Console Project in VS. In Program.cs I added my code. Here is complete code of Program.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        internal class A { }
        public class B : A { }          // Error

        static void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, `internal` _can_ be exposed for use outside the assembly via the [InternalsVisibleTo attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) so perhaps this is the reasoning behind it. I'll see if I can find a specific entry in the C# specification.

Comment: Try 3 works for me, ie. fails to compile with inconsistent accessibility error.

Comment: I also thought of InternalsVisibleTo attribute, but what if I don't mention this in my assembly file. There must be another reason for this.

Comment: Actually, I just did a copy/paste test of your "Try 3" in LINQPad and it failed (inconsistent accessibility error); are you _sure_ what you posted is what you have compiled in visual studio?

Comment: @amnezjak You mean that you received error when you compiled try 3?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yes. I created a new console project and pasted these lines. And it didn't gave any compilation error.

Comment: @well that's strange. My Program.cs file contain only these lines and main function. And it compile successfully.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair but it should give compilation error. As sub class is more accessible than base class.

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior as @ChrisSinclair: I don't get your third example to compile. It fails with _"Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'Namespace.A' is less accessible than class 'Namespace.B'"_.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I have edited the question. Whole code is present there.

Comment: @FredrikMörk then why I am not receiving this error?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez See the answer by Chris. I was writing the same thing as he posted it :-)

Comment: As a side note, this question works as a schoolbook example of why Jon Skeet always stresses that you should include a "short, but _complete_" program in the question. Once the question was edited, the problem was obvious. Before that, a mystery :-)

Comment: Well these are those minor mistakes which are not easy to find. You keep on finding, finding and finding. And in the end you come to know that oh this was the mistake.

Comment: Here's a puzzle for you to see if you understand the rule. `public class Alpha { protected internal class Bravo {} }` in assembly Alpha.DLL, and `public class Charlie : Alpha { xxx class Delta : Bravo {} }` in assembly Charlie.DLL. What are the legal values of accessibility modifier `xxx`?

Comment: @EricLippert Delta class will be private.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez [It's a trap!](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/10/29/what-does-protected-internal-mean.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are placing your nested classes *within* another `internal` class.

For example, given:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    internal class A { }
    public class B : A { }
}
```

It *will* compile because the `internal` modifier of the wrapping class makes the `public` modifier on class `B` moot. Rather, type `B`'s accessibility is limited by its wrapped class `Program` -- its accessibility domain is `internal` as well.

If you update it to be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}

internal class A { }
public class B : A { }
```

It will throw the inconsistent visibility compiler error. Or if you redefine `Program` to be `public` instead of `internal` it will also throw the error. In this case, `B`'s accessibility domain is now `public` and no longer limited by `Program`'s `internal` accessibility domain.

---

From the C# specification [3.5.2 Accessibility Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691128%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The accessibility domain of a nested member M declared in a type T
>   within a program P is defined as follows (noting that M itself may
>   possibly be a type):
>
> If the declared accessibility of M is public, the accessibility domain of M is the accessibility domain of T.

And the [MSDN's description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd74a9ww.aspx) of Accessibility Domain:

> If the member is nested within another type, its accessibility domain
>   is determined by both the accessibility level of the member and the
>   accessibility domain of the immediately containing type.

If the wrapping type `Program` is `internal`, then the nested type `B` being `public` will have its accessibility to match `Program`, thus it is treated as `internal` and no compiler error is thrown.

Comment: Yes, it failed now. I put them outside program class. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I think I found the entry in the C# specification that describes this behaviour. Good question!

Comment: Nice use of the specification here.

Comment: @EricLippert I learn from the best. BTW, thoroughly enjoying the annotated C# specification hard-cover even though I haven't found the time to finish it yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

private inherited classes can not accessible in other classes when you inherit private class with other public class then it contains the reference of private class and its data so it is not possible.

```
abstract class test
    {
        public abstract void add();
        public int num1;
        public string str;
    }
class test3 : test1
    {
        public override void add()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

both classes are private.
if you use internal then you can access only in assembly.